# Media min-width display is overwritten by class style

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to show a `<span>` when `@media (min-width: 600px)` and in other cases to hide that `<span>`

So i've created a class called `elimina-text` with display set to `none` then in media query i'm setting that class to display `inline` but the media query is overwritten and the text is not shown...

So my anchor where i have to hide the text looks like this

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .elimina-text {
    display: inline;
  }
}

.elimina-text {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<a _ngcontent-qmm-c108="" href="" apphref="" class="text-muted button-remove" ng-reflect-href=""><i _ngcontent-qmm-c108="" class="material-icons">delete</i><span _ngcontent-qmm-c108="" class="elimina-text">Elimina</span></a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the order of the CSS.

```css
.elimina-text {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .elimina-text {
    display: inline;
  }
}
```

```html
<a _ngcontent-qmm-c108="" href="" apphref="" class="text-muted button-remove" ng-reflect-href=""><i _ngcontent-qmm-c108="" class="material-icons">delete</i><span _ngcontent-qmm-c108="" class="elimina-text">Elimina</span></a>
```

Comment: I gave an answer using! Important, and I could not even think that this is the order of building the rules :))

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov yeah I saw, nice try :P People tend to use `!important` but it's a very bad habit.

Comment: yes, I agree that it is bad practice to use an `!important`.But sometimes you can't do without an `!important` :))

Comment: I couldn't imagine that order in css matters, thank you